# Background-img align responsive?

Tags: css, background, alignment, background-image, css-position

http://lucasdebelder.be/stack/index.html

Make sure to check it out at 1680px width, then it's perfectly aligned together but if I make my screen bigger or smaller in width it doesn't align anymore any idea how I can get around this issue?

I'm trying to recreate my [Dribbble shot](https://dribbble.com/shots/3876778-Geek-Fysiek-Landing).

Snippet of code.

```css
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    
    background: #F1F1F1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 90px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    border-radius: 15px;
    
    background-image: url("http://svgur.com/i/3W7.svg");
    background-position: 129% 38%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 752px;
    
}
#section0 {
    background-image: url("http://svgur.com/i/3W7.svg");
    background-position: 100% 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:  750px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
            </section>
```

EDIT: It's hard to recreate this in a small jsfiddle, keep that in mind but then you get to see the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet seems to be a little bit broken, but I was able to produce the desired effect by using the unit `vw` for your background position, which is dependant on the viewport width.

```
#section0 {
background-image: url(../img/1/bol.svg), url(../img/1/vlekBG.svg);
background-position: 0vw bottom, 61vw;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: auto, 750px;
}


.wrapper {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
height: 80%;
width: 80%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
background: #F1F1F1;
box-shadow: 0 0 90px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
border-radius: 15px;
background-image: url(../img/1/vlekBG.svg);
background-position: 51vw;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 752px;
```

These are the changes I made in the developer tools and the imaged stayed aligned, independet of the viewport width.

Edit: changed the code a little, because I didn't realize there were two background images in `#section0`

Comment: Thanks a lot! But after 750 height it becomes a square?

Comment: Oh apologies, I didn't realize there were two background images. My repositioning resulted in the first background image overlaying the second one, which is what produced the weird looking square effect. I changed up the code a little and it should work fine now! That's a neat design btw haha